# Java - how to use html in resource load image on local device

Tags: java, webview, javafx-webengine

I'm using WebEngine(WebView) load html file in resource

```
URL mapURL = getClass().getResource("/com/yoouppos/resources/aaaaa.html");
webEngine.load(mapURL.toExternalForm());
```

And aaaaa.html contain image tag

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='googleMap'>
        <center><img id="pic" src="file:///D:/Dropbox/VietOCR/fax-orders/old_3.jpg" width="auto" height="100%"/></center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run project by NetBean then image will be show.
But when I do "clear and build" by NetBean, after that I run jar file in dist folder then image not show.

I want to show image was stored in local on html.

Answer (score 0):

Package your image `old_3.jpg` in the same location as your aaaaa.html, and reference it relatively.

`<img src="old_3.jpg"/>`

Comment: The location of old_3.jpg and aaaaa.html are different.
old_3.jpg was stored in D:/Dropbox/VietOCR/fax-orders/ folder and
aaaaa.html was store in resource

Comment: @wind Put the image in the resource location, so it comes along with your code & html.

Comment: This function is show image in local folder (such as D:/Dropbox/VietOCR/fax-orders/old_3.jpg). that path will be change by user, So can't put the image in resource.

Answer (score 0):

Place Image in Raw folder along with HTML File and then load the html file using url:

```
WV.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/aaaaa.html");
```

Comment: This is java application, don't android application